# Multiple list-groups on a single page, but each list-group allows an unique selection

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have three single column list-group's on my page and allow the user to select an item from each group. However, the list-groups are all linked  and I haven't been able to figure out how to keep them as individual list-groups.

I setup up a quick [Plunker link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKI9nGeVsl0vrJTadW9G?p=preview) so you could see what I'm trying to do.

I'm also not sure why each column of lists is offset by the previous column.

Here's the HTML that I'm playing with as I try to figure out how to do this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>
        Select one from each column.
    </h3>

    <div>
      <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">Select Opp</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="oppname" class="col-md-4 list-group">
      <div class="no-margin">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Aelia
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="no-margin">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Del Monte
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">Select Id</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="oppid" class="col-md-4 list-group">
      <div class="no-margin">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Id: 1724
            </a>
        <div class="no-margin">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Id: 1675
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">Select Size</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="oppsize" class="col-md-4 list-group">
      <div class="no-margin">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Size: 24
            </a>
        <div class="no-margin">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Size: 75
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its weird that it doesn't work by default groupings.

Here is a solution in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9nmvdq6/)

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">One</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
</div>

<div class="list-group">
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">One</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">One</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
  <a  href="#" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
</div>
```

and add this sibling js to do the selection like this

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-group a', function (e) {
   $(this).addClass('active');
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

and Viola.